# Geometry Nodes: how to shade smooth a booleaned object

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made this two-walled sphere that is perforated with cylinders. The wall of the cyclinders between the two spheres creates a connection between the two spheres:

[image]

[image]

Node tree:

[image]

I would like this object to shade smooth, but that gives this ugly geometry:

[image]

I tried to make a seam with the `intersecting edges` output of the `mesh boolean` node with the `seperate geometry` node, but that makes the internal sphere disappear.

Does anyone know a good solution? My goal is to make everything smooth and the faces of the cylinder remains between the two spheres round.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add "Split Edges" node before "Set Shade Smooth" and conect the "intersecting edges output" to "selection" input of Split Edges.

[image: Edge split]

<sub>(Blender 3.3+)</sub>